# MVC3 Razor Get all data from models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've made a CRUD MVC app which has something called `Parts` that are in certain relationships with each other.

```
PartMain      - o:m Section, o:m Report
PartSection   - m:o Main, o:m Property
PartProperty  - m:o Section, Contains MainID for sorting purposes, SortByMainID
PartReport    - m:o Main
```

All models are working and everything is ok on that part. Now I wish to generate a View that will show all data related to lets say selected `PartMain`. Like so:

```
PartMain: Name, Desc, etc... rest of data
    PartSection1: data...
        PartProperty1: data.. (all properties in relationship with that section)
    PartSection2: data... (all sections in relationship with selected PartMain)
        PartProperty1: data.. (all properties in relationship with that section)
    PartReport: data.... (all reports with selected PartMain)
```

I know I should do something like `foreach` loops in `View` but I'm having trouble grasping the logic, can anyone help?

Thanks.

`PartMain` contains Name and Desc properties, also is in o:m `PartSection`, and o:m `PartReport`. `PartSection` contains Name and Desc properties, also is in o:m `PartProperty`. `PartProperty` contains Name and Desc. `PartReport` contains Name and Version.

So what I want to do would be with pseudo code something like.
**I tried this in controller**, passed data with viewbag but nothing came back

```
pMainID = selectedMainID;
PartMain partMain = db.PartMain.Find(pMainID);
ViewBag.Name = partMain.Name
ViewBag.Desc = partMain.Desc

var partSections = db.PartSection.Where(s => s.pMainID = pMainID);

foreach (var partSec in partSections)
{
    ViewBag.PartSecName = partSec.Name
    ViewBag.PartSecDesc = partSec.Desc

    var partProperties = db.PartProperties.Where(p => p.pSecID = partSec.ID);
    foreach(var partProp in partProperties)
    {
        ViewBag.PartPropName = partProp.Name
        ViewBag.PartPropDesc = partProp.Desc
    }
}
```

Now that should output something like I mentioned above. Of course this code won't work but that should be the general idea. That's why I ask for help. Thank you.

Comment: I moved everything to View as inline code using `@{}` and it worked.

Comment: Your code didn't work because every time you assign a value to ViewBag.XXX you throw away the old value.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, that's why i moved it as inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
var pMainID = selectedMainID;
PartMain partMain = db.PartMain.Find(pMainID);

ViewBag.Part = partMain;

ViewBag.Sections = db.PartSection
    .Where(s => s.pMainID = pMainID)
    .Select(s => new
    {
        Section = s,
        Proeprties = db.PartProperties.Where(p => p.pSecID = partSec.ID)
    });
```

View:

```
<h1>@ViewBag.Part.Name</h1>
<p>@ViewBag.Part.Desc</p>

@foreach(var section in ViewBag.Sections)
{
    <h2>@section.Section.Name</h2>
    <p>@section.Section.Desc</p>

    <dl>
    @foreach(var property in section.Properties)
    {
        <dt>@property.Name</dt>
        <dd>@property.Desc</dd>
    }
    </dl>
}
```

Comment: My 2nd `code` part was only a display how it should look. I couldn't really get it working :( I'll provide some more code to make it clearer.